# Array of unlimited polymorphic pointers as dummy variable

Tags: arrays, pointers, polymorphism, fortran

I want to define a subroutine that has an array of unlimited polymorphic pointers on the input. 
The simplified problem in three steps (the problem appears in step 3):

1.
For a single pointer this can be done like:

```
module def

type :: type1
   real :: x
end type

type :: type2
   real(8) :: y
end type

type(type1),target :: a
type(type2),target :: b

class(*),pointer :: p

contains

subroutine printer(p)
   class(*),pointer :: p
   select type(p)
   type is (type1)
      print*,p%x
   type is (type2)
      print*,p%y
   end select
end subroutine

end module

program test
use def
a%x=3e0
b%y=5d0

p=>a
call printer(p)
p=>b
call printer(p)
end program
```

2.
If I want to generalize this to arrays of pointers I need to define a type inculding my pointer and define an array of the derived type. So in a first step I defined my type and tried it again for a single pointer. Here, I realized that I need an `associate` name inside of my subroutine for the `select type` construct while the rest extends straight forward:

```
module def

type :: type1
   real :: x
end type

type :: type2
   real(8) :: y
end type

type(type1),target :: a
type(type2),target :: b

type point
   class(*),pointer :: p
end type

type(point) :: p

contains

subroutine printer(z)
   class(point) :: z
   associate (o=>z%p)
      select type(o)
      type is (type1)
         print*,o%x
      type is (type2)
         print*,o%y
      end select
   end associate
end subroutine

end module

program test
use def
a%x=3e0
b%y=5d0

p%p=>a
call printer(p)
p%p=>b
call printer(p)
end program
```

3.
But if I now define the desired array of unlimited polymorphic pointers and change my subroutine accordingly, like shown here:

```
module def

type :: type1
   real :: x
end type

type :: type2
   real(8) :: y
end type

type(type1),target :: a
type(type2),target :: b

type point
   class(*),pointer :: p
end type

type(point) :: p(1:2)

contains

subroutine printer(z)
   class(point),dimension(1:) :: z
   integer :: j
   associate (o=>z%p)
   do j=1,size(z,1)
      select type(o)
      type is (type1)
         print*,o(j)%x
      type is (type2)
         print*,o(j)%y
      end select
   end do
   end associate
end subroutine

end module

program test
use def
a%x=3e0
b%y=5d0

p(1)%p=>a
p(2)%p=>b
call printer(p)
end program
```

I get the error:

```
   associate (o=>z%p)
                 1
Error: Component to the right of a part reference with nonzero rank must not have the POINTER attribute at (1)
```

I understand the error, arrays of pointers are just not part of the fortran standard. But at the moment I don't see any way around it. Without this `associate` construct I can't do the type selection, since this produces the error:

```
      select type(z%p)
                  1
Error: Selector in SELECT TYPE at (1) is not a named variable; use associate-name=>
```

Comment: Phew, that's a lot of code, and I'm too busy to read all that... Could you construct a **minimal** example?

Comment: Arrays of pointers aren't allowed, but you can create a user-defined type that contains a pointer and make an array of elements of that type.  Also, `real(8)` is not portable.  You might want to look into the types provided by the module ISO_FORTRAN_ENV.

Comment: The OP has exactly such a derived type in his code.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: This is kind of the minimal working example. To see the error it is (as mentioned) enough to look on the last step.

Comment: I was commenting on the statements: "I understand the error, arrays of pointers are just not part of the fortran standard. But at the moment I don't see any way around it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this

```
subroutine printer(z)
   class(point),dimension(1:) :: z
   integer :: j
   do j=1,size(z,1)
      select type(o=>z(j)%p)
      type is (type1)
         print*,o%x
      type is (type2)
         print*,o%y
      end select
   end do
end subroutine
```

the association is part of the `select type` construct.

Explanation of the error message `Error: Component to the right of a part reference with nonzero rank must not have the POINTER attribute at (1)`: It is not allowed to make any reference as `a%b` where `a` is an array and `b` is `allocatable` or `pointer`.

This is because the individual `b`'s are randomly placed in the memory and arrays in Fortran standard must be describable by a descriptor with constant strides between the elements.

Comment: To clarify for @PeMa, your error is that your declare `z` as an array, but then access it as a scalar.  The code above just fixes your accessing of `z` properly as an array.

Comment: @casey: I don't think that this is the reason for the error. If z%p wouldn't be an array of pointers but a "normal" array, it would work.

Comment: @Vladimir F: Thanks a lot already! Actually this doesn't seem to solve my actual problem entirely but I need some time to descibe why.

Comment: @PeMa that is the reason of the error, precisely because fortran does not allow for arrays of pointers.

Comment: @Vladimir F thanks for adding the explanation. I got the point now.

Comment: @Vladimir F: Originally between the `associate` and the `do` loop I wanted to call yet another subroutine which itself depends on the whole array of pointers. This is (as you reasoned already) also not possible. But I think I found a way around this. If not I might open another threat soon. And mark this one as solved. Thanks again for your help.